# Spark Dataframe Pivot w/o Aggregate

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pivot

I've got a bunch of json document, that correspond to a database change.. that resembles this format:

```
{
    "key": "abc",
    "timestamp": 1573085110000,
    "cols": [{
            "name": "COL1",
            "value": "14",
        }, {
            "name": "COL2",
            "value": "Some Text",
        }
    ]
}
```

Loading this to a spark dataframe yields:

```
+---+-------------+--------------------+
|key|    timestamp|                cols|
+---+-------------+--------------------+
|abc|1573084821000|[[COL1, 14], [COL...|
|def|1573171513000|[[COL1, xx], [COL...|
|   |             |                    |
+---+-------------+--------------------+
```

I exploded the `cols` array, so now the db column names are on the rows, urgh

```
+---+----+---------+
|key|name|    value|
+---+----+---------+
|abc|COL1|       14|
|abc|COL2|Some Text|
|   |    |         |
+---+----+---------+
```

Now, pivot i figured.. so i started writing:

```
dt.groupBy($"key").pivot("name").agg($"value")
```

at which point obviously i realised spark doesn't allow aggregations on non-numeric cols..

so essentially, given the irritating way in which the data is defined in json.. is there a better way to achieve this:

```
+---+----+---------+
|key|COL1|     COL2|
+---+----+---------+
|abc|14  |Some Text|
|   |    |         |
+---+----+---------+
```

need to head home, been a long day.. probably missing something obvious, ta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not 5 mins after posting this i figured it out..

```
dt.groupBy($"key").pivot($"name").agg(first($"value"))
```